# How to output two responses.xpath in the same json field?

Tags: scrapy

It's possible concatenate two `response.xpath` in one? I have, for example i have one `response.xpath` to movie name and other for the director. But instead output this in two lines and the json i do like to have it in one.

Like this in the `json` :

```
{"movie" = "Pulp Fiction, Quentin Tarantino", "year":"1994"}
```

The `HTML` is like :

```
<div class="movie_col">
  <div class="movie_director"><h1>Pulp Fiction</h1></div>
  <div class="director-link"><a><span itemprop="director"> 
    Quentin Tarantino 
  </span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just concatenate the two values? `response.xpath('//div[@class="movie_director"]/h1/text()').extract_first() + ', ' + response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="director"]/text()').extract_first()`

Comment: This works. I just notice now than I was concatenating wrong. Thank you.